# failed to update - internet connection error

Tags: 12.04, updates, internet-connection

i am using ubuntu 12.04 lts.
i m trying to update but i get an error

> Failed to download repository information
>   Check your Internet connection.

My internet connection is fine.

when i see details of the error an get this

> W:Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
>   , E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

any help please

Comment: The instructions here may fix the issue: http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome_3.html

Answer (score -2):

Go to Software Sources > Other Software and Uncheck the checkbox against http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release and Click on Close.

Now go and check for updates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but unfortunatelly it doesnt give me that option.I mean i dont have the http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release . but i have the http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/stable main and http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/stable main(source code) any help now? :-)

Comment: i removed the above reps and everything is ok. thanks mate :-)